# I can not get rid of the border in a gwt frame

Tags: gwt, iframe

I can not get rid of the border in a gwt frame

here is my css rule

```
.gwt-Frame {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    color: white;
    border: 0px none;
    margin: 0px
}
```

what am I doing wrong? It is really frustrating I tried this for hours? help please?

Comment: How are you applying that CSS rule? If you change it to have a 100px-wide red border, does it come out looking like you'd expect? If it's in a `CssResource` you'll need to call `ensureInjected()` to apply those style rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are applying css correctly i.e. using `ensureInjected()` if its in `CssResource`, in `app.gwt.xml` check you included theme and verify css using any developer tool (firebug) in browser.

You can always use

```
frame.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(0, Unit.PX);
```

Comment: note that this does not work for ie6 and ie7 this is the work around I used. DOM.setIntAttribute(frame.getElement(), "frameBorder", 0);

Answer (score 1):

You could just add !important tag infront of your css rule

```
    border: 0px none !important;
```